# D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Tags: java, android

**Хотел бы отобразить карту на андроиде используя java, но не получается**

```
mapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapquestOSM", 2, 15, 256, ".png", new String[]{}));
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
IMapController mapController = mapView.getController();
mapController.setZoom(10);
GeoPoint startPt = new GeoPoint(38.5357,68.77905);
mapController.setCenter(startPt);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: а что не получается?

Comment: карту не показывает, какие то проблемы с декодированием